# Where is the Remove Personal Information item in Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, compatibility, microsoft-word-2011

In Word for Mac 2011, there is a checkbox in the Preferences -> Security for `Remove personal information from this file on save`.  Where would this checkbox be set in Word 2007 on windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, go to **Office Button - Prepare - Properties** to edit PII in the document.

Or go to **Prepare - Inspect Document** and use the wizard to remove PII.

This should be the same in OSX.